# Android Studio compile and run project (developed in linux ubuntu) in windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, project, migrate

I am facing a major issue, I developed a project in AS in linux ubuntu and now need to compile and run it in Windows 10.

I installed AS in windows 10 and everything seems fine but as soon as I import the project in windows 10 AS it seems the import process is **stuck**.
It`s only showing "**gladle build running..**"

I already tried to clean the project from cmd prompt --> **gradlew clean build --stacktrace** but it says build successfull.
However as soon as I want to build the project in AS itself the gradle build process gets stuck. (running for 20 minutes now).

Console is showing:

```
11:00   Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
```

I tried to:

```
- delete local.properties
- delete .gradle dir in project itself
```

Nothing seems to help.

If you need more details, just ask please.

What can I do? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of just copying the project in a flash drive, push it to github or bitbucket from the ubuntu system, and pull it from the windows 10 computer.

Comment: That would be an idea yes, pull it from Android Studio or can I also use Sourcetree for instance?

Comment: @Light, did that and gradle build running again for 11 minutes?
Any idea please?

Comment: This is probably related to internet connection. When you copying project from one computer to another computer, the gradle binary and dependencies files are not copied. So, when you're trying to opening the project, it will download them first.

Comment: @simon sorry for the late reply this SE app doesn't send me notifications.. Just disable offline mode and let android studio download the required or missing plugins and libraries